# Trouble with updating my system - Huawei p8 Lite

Tags: updates, 6.0-marshmallow, huawei

I'm currently on Android 5.* and I wanted to upgrade it to 6.0 - I downloaded [official firmware](http://consumer.huawei.com/pk/support/products/downloads/detail/p8-lite-pk.htm?id=81665) and the tutorial gave me 2 ways of installing it. One way is through system (Settings -> Updates -> ... -> Local Update) and the other way is by holding appropiate buttons while booting. **I HAVE copied update.app to external SD into 'dload' directory!** The problem is, that my device has **TWRP** installed and whenever I want to upgrade firmware, it sends me to TWRP instead of sending me to upgrade recovery section.

In fact, I can get to EMUI upgrade recovery mode, but when I do, it just 'checks' the update file and second after starting to install it, it says, that install has failed. I'm 100% sure firmware is correct and I'm doing everything as I should.

The question is: Is there any other way of installing Android 6.0 on my device? It is rooted and bootloader is unlocked. Maybe I can do it somehow through bootloader?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TWRP is a custom recovery. You have to do these things before uphrading

- Uninstall TWRP ( after taking a backup)
- Install stock recovery
- Unroot
- lock bootloader
- Upgrade using the key combination method, which wipes data and does a clean install- always preferred for a version upgrade
- Unlock bootloader and root

This [XDA post](http://www.xda-developers.com/xda-external-link/install-official-android-6-0-on-huawei-p8-lite/) does not talk about rooted devices but [this](http://www.android.gs/update-huawei-p8-lite-android-6-0-marshmallow/) mentions that out will not work on rooted devices. Procedure is from my experience with Honor 6

Comment: So there's no other way to run UPDATE.APP?

Comment: No. To the best of my knowledge